# Laravel xampp migrate missing driver windowns 10

Tags: laravel, windows, xampp, migrate

Windows 10, using xampp v3.2.4, Laravel 8.12. Whenever running php artisan migrate I get `could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`.

I've tried just about every 'solution' on stack. I've updated the `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` file, by uncommenting `extension=pdo_mysql` and `extension=mysqli` plus setting `extension_dir="C:/xampp/php/ext"` with no luck.

I had no problems creating the database by logging into MySQL on the command line with `mysql -u root` and creating the database.

In the env file, `

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testme
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

`and`database.php`it's set to`'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),` I'm out of solutions. Any help is much appreciated. The database shows on the PHPMyAdmin Dashboard.

Comment: After changes on configuration file you must need to restart the apache on xampp

Comment: Yeah, I did restart Apache after changes. Thnaks.

Comment: I forgot to mention I uninstalled xampp, and installed Apache, PHP 8, and MySQL separately, and got the same error when migrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling Laravel, then reinstalling the migrate command is now working. Although I have no idea what caused it to now work correctly.